# Terminal Character Encoding Issue BitchX

Tags: terminal, fonts, character-encoding, terminal-emulator

I ran [BitchX](http://wiki.bitchx.org/faq%3ageneral_information) on three different Linux OS-es because I got this weird � (question mark) on two of them (Linux OpenSUSE 11.4 and BackTrack 5 R1) using yakuake/konsole (OpenSUSE) and terminator/tilda (BT 5 R1).

However, on PuppyLinux Lucid 528 with RoxTerm the character is displayed as it should be (it is the Greek character "fi"). Now, on both SUSE and BT I have checked to see the value of $LC_CTYPE, and it's the same as in Puppy Linux (namely en_US, so no utf-8 encoding).

I've experimented on both SUSE and BT with different character encodings (from terminal's settings), I've noticed the changes, but the text was still sometimes garbled, instead of the question mark I got some weird unintelligible "u"-s (in Puppy it is always displayed correctly).

What could cause this annoying problem?
What could be different and how can I check the difference?

Comment: What caused this character to appear?

Comment: I just ran the application and saw it..it's a wrongful replacement of the Greek character.

Comment: SOLVED I set the value of $TERM to 'linux' (it was set to 'xterm' by default). Added "export TERM='linux'" (without the double quotes) to .bashrc and now the character is displayed properly and I can even see the ASCII coloured drawings.

Comment: UPDATE The tweak ONLY works with gnome terminals installed on either KDE or Gnome desktop environment (terminals that support it: gnome-terminal, terminator, ROXterm, tilda, guake). It does not work in Konsole or Yakuake, not even in Urxvt.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things going on here.

Can you first make sure that `LC_CTYPE=en_US` does mean "no utf-8"?

The `nl_langinfo` function can help, for example:

```
$ python
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, 'en_US')
'en_US'
>>> locale.nl_langinfo(locale.CODESET)
'ISO-8859-1'
```

Secondly, it would be helpful to try changing only one variable at a time.  For example, if RoxTerm works in PuppyLinux, does it work in OpenSUSE and/or BackTrack?  And can you also say which version of `BitchX` you're using, in case it makes a difference?

Finally, IRC doesn't really supply any character encoding information, so the server and all the users in a channel have to agree on a character encoding.  I think these days most users use UTF-8, so maybe you should try changing your settings to UTF-8?

---

UPDATE

You said BitchX doesn't support UTF-8.

Then I think you are going to have problems talking to other users.

But if everyone else is talking Greek, and also using BitchX, then perhaps you want to use the [Greek ISO-8859-7 character set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-7).

On my system, the only two locales that support ISO-8859-7 out of the box are Greek language ones, e.g. `el_GR.iso88597`.

Run `locale -a` to see a full list of your options, and choose one that includes that character set.

Comment: I get this error when running the code:`>>> locale.setlocale('en_US')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 513, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
TypeError: an integer is required` I have tried with RoxTerm in BackTrack, and didn't make a difference: the character is displayed improperly. Here's the [BitchX] (http://wiki.bitchx.org/svn_instructions) version I'm using, i.e. the latest. BitchX doesn't support utf-8, but it should work, since it works in Puppy.

Comment: This shall be tried as: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_CTYPE, 'en_US')

Comment: Mikel, thank you so much for your time and your answer. Please see my comment to my question. I have found the solution meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Question mark in rhomb likely means that your client program accepts character and passes it to displaying engine (am I correct that bitchX is only terminal program?), but terminal fails to render it. So it is likely terminal configuration problem - e.g. the selected font doesn't contain glyphs for Greek characters. You can test it by copy&paste from this terminal to another one with something like "hexdump -C" running - it would show phi codepoint (U+03C6, so `CF 86' in hexdump of utf-8). If so, try to select font which supports Greek.

Seeing something like \u03C6, , etc. means likely locale is broken (not Unicode) so client accepts characters, apply Unicode treating to them but then fails to output them directly and switches to fallback mode. So, I guess SuSE and BT setups both have en_US as alias to non-Unicode coding, likely ISO-8859-1. Try to set en_US.UTF-8 directly and compare effects.

Comment: Update: I tried to use Urxvt in Puppy Linux to see if it makes any difference from ROXterm. Surprise: it does NOT display it as it should be, so the only console that works is ROXTerm (but ONLY on Puppy Linux). It's not a font issue, since ROXTerm uses Liberation and I changed to Liberation in the other terminals, without any result. I'm puzzled.

Comment: My systems are FreeBSD8 at home and OpenSuSE (12.1; short time ago it was 11.4) at work. Both have no problems with phi in terminal if configured in UTF-8, but I prefer good old xterm for this. The font at home system is xos4-terminus-...-iso10646-1. I don't know the Fedora specifics but suggest first to solve correct displaying of Greek letters in terminal on all systems and, when succeeded, switch to teach BitchX.